# How to load data uri links in IOS home screen web apps?

Tags: iphone-standalone-web-app, data-uri

If I open the following page in Safari on an iPad running 6.1.2, clicking on the first link opens a new tab with 'Hello World!', and the second loads 'Hello Again!' in the iframe.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a href="data:text/plain,Hello World!" target="_blank">data: uri new tab test</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="data:text/plain,Hello Again!" target="dataframe">data: uri iframe test</a>
    </p>
    <iframe name="dataframe" width="500" height="100"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I add this page to the home screen, in the resulting app the links do nothing.

Is there any method to get data URI links to load in an IOS home screen web app, either by loading Safari to display the content, or by embedding it somehow?

Or perhaps some other method for a home screen web app to locally store and display PDFs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502888/using-apple-mobile-web-app-capable-disables-data-uri-on-ios