# Using apple-mobile-web-app-capable disables data: uri on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari

I created an application that uses the `data:` uri mechanism to open a file in the calendar on iOS. It works fine if you run it from mobile Safari, it works if you add a shortcut to your home screen, but as soon as I add:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

… to make it behave a little bit more app-alike, it no longer works. (I also have to say that it *never* works in Chrome for iOS.) Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds? Hidden options I'm not aware of?

Comment: I got the Same Problem. Guess that's a new behaviour Sinne iOS 6. My workaround is to modify the href attribute:

Comment: **http.//www.mysite.com?datastring=THE_STRING**. This leaves the WebApp and pops up Safari. Herr I retrieve the get variable and redirect to the datauri string. - Yes, security concerns (get-method), but my App is offline. Yes, very nasty...